# MediaRecorder start failed: -38 on Some Devices

Tags: android, media, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I am creating an app which is able to record surround sound in background and I follow all the states of Media Recorder which work fine on some devices but throw following exception on some devices too.

```
06-19 18:21:35.658: E/MediaRecorder(7439): start failed: -38
06-19 18:21:35.658: W/System.err(7439): java.lang.IllegalStateException
06-19 18:21:35.658: W/System.err(7439):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
```

I search that but found nothing for this error code. Can somebody tell me what is the meaning of this error code and how to resolve that.

I know it might be a duplicate one [android: media recorder : start failed: -38](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675120/android-media-recorder-start-failed-38) but no help on that post too.

This demo works on Samsung Nexus and Nexus 4 but continuously crashing on Samsung S II.
Thanks

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution, same happens to me on some devices. Have you solved the problem yet?

Comment: I've been trying to solve it for days..

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue with MediaRecorder, and the reason is that your mic is occupied by another thread.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it? If there isn't, this perhaps isn't answer worthy.

Comment: Please explain how to find the other thread, or provide work around.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with -38 , in my case i found that i've had other background service that is using AudioRecord that uses the mic.....